# What is the Top Gun Medal for?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

A few times I have received the Top Gun medal/commendation in Halo 5.  What is this for? I have been trying to associate it with my game-play, but most battles are too fast for me to correlate it to anything.  Perhaps, first bullet out of a clip used to kill someone?  I do receive this a lot when playing in the SWAT playlist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually just found my answer on a Halo 5 forum:

> **Top Gun:** Be the first player on your team to reach 10 kills

[Source](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/forums/6e35355aecdf4fd0acdaee3cc4156fd4/topics/new-halo-5-medals-requirements-list/9bae181a-b444-4943-a260-1c3408c67f4d/posts)

Edit: As well I found all medals on [Halo Waypoint](https://www.halowaypoint.com)
[image]